“… keep at least $20 on a dollar bill” What does ‘on’ mean here?

“The amount of money you should start with in a cash register is between $100 and $150. Also, a good rule of thumb is to keep at least $20 ON a dollar bill and $20 ON a $5 bill. That amount allows you to return the change to your customers within one sales shift.”

From: www.ydcrpos.com

This is a bit of garbage that has been copy and pasted on a few websites, probably created by a non-English speaker. It's the only usage of the phrase.

Google search: No results found for "on a dollar bill" -"character on" -"colour on" -"seal on" -"States on" -"stamp on" -"mark on" "seal on" -"star on". Non-standard; *voting to close.

Considering the context, the use of "on" seems incorrect here. It would be more clear to say "...keep at least $20 in one dollar bills and $20 in five dollar bills"
The word "on" tends to be used when referring to surfaces, like if the money were to be placed on top of the cash register. While "in" is appropriate for referring to amounts of money and is short hand for "in the form of XYZ dollar bills".

Certainly if you google the phrase, there's only one occurrence which seems to have been cut-and-pasted on about a dozen websites. Almost certainly a mistake. I can't find any legitimate examples of variations on the phrase (although there's a lot of perfectly-grammatical discussion of symbols/pictures/text "on a dollar bill" so it's hard to search).

"On" is the opposite of "off"; (To turn "on" something) Would you turn "on" the television? Can you turn "on" the radio? Or put the drink "on" the table. As well As put your clothes "on". The word "on" can used in many ways.

Downvote is not mine, but that isn't the only meaning of on.  Think surfaces.

This doesn't answer the question, what does "on" mean in the phrase "$20 ON a dollar bill"? Is this structure commonly used? Is it used in the US? It sounds unusual to me.  Why isn't it "… have/keep a single $20 bill and four bills of $5 in the cash registry”?
